# cocos2d with view controller

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d and view controllers in my game. I wants to call a view controller using cocos2d scene using following code

```
PlayAgainViewController* playAgain = [[PlayAgainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayAgainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:playAgain.view];
```

its adding view controller view on game scene but not calling another view controller by using view added on openGl view.

Answer (score 1):

//if UR_COCOS2D_VERSION_2_0

```
  AppController *app =  (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
  [app.navController presentModalViewController:playAgain animated:YES];
```

//Cocos2D 1.0, use  viewController property in appDelegate.

```
 AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];              
 [app.viewController presentModalViewController:playAgain animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.as : it helps me a lot and solved my problem.
But now i am facing a new problem which is when i am calling view controller from cocos2d layer using your answer its working excellent :), but when i want to call another view controller which is calling EAGLView

Comment: @user1141020, once u done with playAgain view controller call [app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]...that's it.

Comment: but this is not calling init function of opengl view

Comment: [PlayAgainViewController alloc] initWithNibName, u can override initWithNibName if u want to do anything in init. Or u can track in viewDidLoad..or in other view delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your answer.as :

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    PlayAgainViewController* playAgain = [[PlayAgainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayAgainViewController" bundle:nil];
    AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.navigationController pushViewController:playAgain animated:YES];
```

it helps me a lot and solved my problem.
But now i am facing a new problem which is when i am calling view controller from cocos2d layer using your answer its working excellent :), but when i want to call another view controller which is calling EAGLView usig following code:

```
 if([[CCDirector sharedDirector] isPaused])
     [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Game scene]];
 else 
     [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[Game scene]];
```

its showing white screen. I think the problem is texture. Can u please tell me how to release textures used in layer while calling view controller.

Comment: why r u using multiple GLView in cocos2D? Is that really necessary?  If yes then u can refer thread sample in cocos2D sdk, they used one more glView at load time to show drawings.

Comment: its my question. I am following game flow in the following manner
main game(cocos2d layer)->game over(view controller which has a button for play again and for many other operation)-> main game(cocos 2d)
So i am not able to play game again.

Comment: my suggestion, use separate cocos2D scene for gameOver and there use ll ur gameOverbuttons, and by pressing play again u just start game scene...no need to use separate view! Refer cocos2D sample to replace scene.

Comment: but i am using many other view controller in my app .So can u please help me why its showing white screen when i am replacing scene. Today you helped me a lot. Thanks(mini jain)